# Cual es el SQL server que tiene la opcion de Email desde servicio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una Db con muchos email quiero usar el SQL server para enviar correo de Publicidad a todos los registrados el problema es que mi SQL server es 2008R2 pero creo es el express o algo asi lo cierto es que no tiene ni las opciones de Mail en **Management** pregunto cual debo descargar que tenga dicha función? Necesito SQL server o cualquier software que me realice dicho trabajo.

[image: Se observa ausencia de complemento de envio de emails]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la version enterprise tiene la opcion de envio de email. Posterior a eso, configurar el profile del email en sql, un sp para envio con un cursos para barrer todos los emails y enviarlo.